# how to insert value in ms access using java

Tags: java, database, ms-access, user-interface, sqlexception

```
try 
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MyDatabase");
    st1=con1.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    System.out.println("Connect database in BallMoves1.java .......");
    /*the below line giving error*/
    rs1 = st1.executeQuery("insert into highscore" + " (score) " + "values('"+score+"')");
    System.out.println("Score is inserted..");
    System.out.println("Score......."+score);
}catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}

/*highscore is table and attributes of table are (sid,score).
```

the resulting error is:

```
Connect database in BallMoves1.java .......
java.sql.SQLException: No ResultSet was produced
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:258)
    at BallMoves1.move(BallMoves1.java:378)
    at BallMoves1.run(BallMoves1.java:223)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)*/
```

Comment: And the error is...? (You should *always* include the details of the error message.) Also, use parameterized SQL instead of putting the value directly into your SQL... and please format your posts more carefully in future, using spaces instead of tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `executeQuery` on something that isn't a query. But instead of calling `execute` with the same SQL, you should use a `PreparedStatement`:

```
String sql = "insert into highscore (score) values (?)";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MyDatabase");
    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
  statement.setInt(1, score);
  statement.executeUpdate();
  conn.commit();
}
```

*Always* use parameterized SQL, instead of plugging the values directly into the SQL - that protects you from SQL injection attacks, conversion errors, and hard-to-read code.

Use a try-with-resources statement (as I have) to automatically close the statement and connection at the end of the block.